# Given a wave function $\psi(x)$, is there always a potential $V(x)$ such that $\psi(x)$ is an eigenstate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

Given any unit norm wave function $\psi(x)$ which is in the Hilbert space, can we always find a $V(x)$ such that the $\psi(x)e^{-i\omega t}$ is a solution of the corresponding Schrödinger equation? (I mean the Hamiltonian which uses the potential $V(x)$.)

Comment: No need to ask for excuse. Once you ask too many questions, the system will automatically temporarily block you :)

Answer (score 9):

I'm not quite sure where OP is going with this, but from a mathematical perspective, assuming that the wave function $\psi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ is twice differentiable and different from zero, consider the (possibly complex) potential

$$ V(x)~:=~\hbar\omega+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{\psi^{\prime\prime}(x)}{\psi(x)}. $$

This will trivially satisfy [TDSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation).

Comment: Thanks for the regularity assumptions, I forgot them in the question. But complex potential wouldn't make sense when it comes to reality, would it? I thought the potential always need to be real. I'd be glad to know any example of real world complex potential.

Comment: @RajeshD There's no complexity there. The $\exp(-i\omega t)$ factor cancels out in the division. The same is for global time-independent phase factor. Without magnetic field, you can always choose the eigenfunction to be real.

Comment: @Qmechanic would this actually work for a solution of a Schrödinger's equation with magnetic field? It seems it wouldn't because the solution can't be chosen real in general then.

Comment: @Ruslan : Thanks. Wonder what happens in the case of non stationary wave function, just from a math point of view.

Comment: @RajeshD a real normalizable wavefunction is an eigenfunction of some Hamiltonian of the form you imply.

Comment: @Qmechanic : The $\psi(x)$ needs to be non zero

Comment: I even saw a perturbation theory that started from a model $\psi^{(0)}$ where the potential difference $V-V^{(0)}$ was treated as a perturbation.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is about physics and not mathematics the point is that the Schrödinger equation is only defined if a real valued potential exists.
So any wave function - defined as a solution of the given equation - has necessarily at least one corresponding potential. If someone wants to solve your intended problem mathematically she should take in account that a wave function in most cases is not different from zero on the whole real axis and that it is usually defined on a three dimensional space.