# A particle of mass $m$ moves in one dimension. How to find energy and potential for given eigenstate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

The exact ground state eigenfunction is given by $$\psi(x)=A\operatorname{sech}(x) \quad ,$$
Where $A$ is the normalisation constant. Find the energy in this state and the potential $V(x)$, given that $V(x)$ tends to zero as $x$ tends to infinity in either direction.

I found the energy by substituting the wave function in Schrödinger's equation and respecting the boundary conditions. I have no idea how to calculate potential.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156373/)

Comment: [Near duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/165321/).